# How to force start animation if view out of window

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a scroll view with several views and only one view can be expanded. When another view gets expanded the already expanded view gets shrunk. But the animation for the not visible item on the screen gets started only when the view gets visible.

So is there a way to force start the animation?

Setting the height for not visible item causes unwanted jumping of scroll Y if the view is on top and view on bottom gets expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody knowing this, I must assume this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and was so happy, that i found the question on SO, only to find out that no one had answered it. I looked around for a solution but didnt really find one. So what i did in the end was to check if the item was in the visible area (was pretty easy for me, since i used a custom pager) and set the animation time on the invisible items to 0. 
Worked for me, but i dont know if this will work/worked for you.

PS: I would have posted a comment instead of an answer but i think i am not allowed yet.

Comment: I could have used View onVisibilityChanged but I'm using API level 7 and that came on 8.

Answer (score -2):

You just invalidate the invisible view by invalidate() method.